# difference between MICRO_KIND and MINI_KIND in mediastore in android?

Tags: android, mediastore

In my android docs i don't have meaning in micro_kind and mini_kind, what is the difference in this two?

When it comes to displaying the Image what the difference in the two?

**FOLLOWUP QUESTION:**
what is the difference in MediaStore.Images and MediaStore.Video and still give the output of an image, the path contain video path, how come even i use mediastore.images.thumbnail.mini_kind its still displaying image also?

```
Bitmap bmp = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(videoPath,
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);

Bitmap bmp = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(videoPath,
                MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
```

Comment: you should ask 2 different question

Comment: [**Here**](http://rdcworld-android.blogspot.in/2013/08/how-to-pick-image-thumb-nail-from.html) I have written small article on this.. will help you

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The difference is in the size (dimensions) of the thumbnail.

- `MINI_KIND: 512 x 384`
- `MICRO_KIND: 96 x 96`

So when it comes to displaying, the difference you will observe will be the difference in dimensions. `MICRO_KIND` is smaller and *square*, while `MINI_KIND` is relatively bigger and *rectangular*.

[`MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.html#MINI_KIND) and [`MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.html#MINI_KIND) are both integers with value `1`

So when you call the methods above, what you are basically doing is:

```
Bitmap bmp = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(videoPath,1);
```

This is the reason it always works.

Just keep in mind as a **convention** to use:

- `MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND` for image thumbnails and,
- `MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND` for video thumbnails,

so as to make the code consistent and readable.

Comment: ahh thanks, now i know, because im conserving spaces, memory, and even performance issues, thanks amulya

Comment: @PioloOpaw I have updated my answer. Do keep in mind to always _accept answers_ if they resolve your problems.

Comment: thans amulya hehe ur d best thnks bro!

Comment: Piolo Opaw, I suspect @Amulya Khare meant a different sort of acceptance. ;)

Comment: is MINI_KIND always the same size? I mean when orginal photo is square by itself will it be stretched?

Comment: What about the MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.FULL_SCREEN_KIND, is it eligible too?