# Getting Fullscreen thumbnails from the mediastore - Android

Tags: android, mediastore

I keep getting an Error 'Unsupported kind: 2' when trying to get a FULL_SCREEN_KIND thumbnail from the mediastore. I know that the URI is a valid image (because I am already getting smaller thumbs beforehand). Where is my error? Thank you.

**My Code**

```
Long myURI = Long.parseLong(record.getString("FILE_ID"));

if (record.getString("FILE_TYPE").equalsIgnoreCase("image")) {

    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(mContext.getContentResolver(), myURI ,MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.FULL_SCREEN_KIND, (BitmapFactory.Options) null);
    return bitmap;

} 

else if (record.getString("FILE_TYPE").equalsIgnoreCase("video")) {

    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(mContext.getContentResolver(), myURI, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.FULL_SCREEN_KIND, (BitmapFactory.Options) null);
    return bitmap;

}
```

**LogCat**

```
06-22 15:24:05.160    3510-3935/com.diverg.tidy I/asd﹕ ID: 50735
06-22 15:24:05.910    3510-3935/com.diverg.tidy W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=21: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41ab3ba8)
06-22 15:24:05.941    3510-3935/com.diverg.tidy E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-8183
Process: com.diverg.tidy, PID: 3510
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported kind: 2
    at android.provider.MediaStore$InternalThumbnails.getThumbnail(MediaStore.java:670)
    at android.provider.MediaStore$Images$Thumbnails.getThumbnail(MediaStore.java:1022)
    at com.diverg.tidy.LightboxImageManager.getBitmap(LightboxImageManager.java:105)
    at com.diverg.tidy.LightboxImageManager.access$400(LightboxImageManager.java:32)
    at            com.diverg.tidy.LightboxImageManager$ImageQueueManager.run(LightboxImageManager.java:250)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.html

It seems the “kind” param should be either MICRO_KIND or MINI_KIND.

Comment: But even in the documentation you linked to, it shows "FULLSCREEN_KIND". How else would one get a large thumbnail of a video? The default Android gallery does it...

Comment: You should read the method declaration not the field declaration, use MINI_KIND if you want a larger thumbnail.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20208007/difference-between-micro-kind-and-mini-kind-in-mediastore-in-android

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I am showing a fullscreen image and wondering if 512 x 384 is big enough. I'm not sure that it is. Is there another method for getting bigger thumbnails besides createScaledBitmap(). Thanks again for your help!

Comment: You can try ThumbnailUtils.http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are on android-8 (Froyo) or above, you can use  `ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail` like this:

```
Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path,
    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.FULL_SCREEN_KIND);
```